# Download file from upload.cc

Tags: html, linux, bash, shell, networking

I'm writing a shell script to download a pic from upload.cc but I always get 403 Forbidden message.

If I get the pic with google chrome browser, it's ok.

I don't know what's going on.

This is my shell script.

```
wget https://upload.cc/i1/2023/03/16/qOC5h3.jpg --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36'
```

Comment: I would’ve honestly expected something closer to 401, or unauthorized. From the MDN, forbidden is for when a user has authenticated but they don’t have permission to do something, where 401 means you haven’t authenticated yet. It seems like you haven’t authenticated, is there something I am missing? Otherwise it could be that they confused 401 and 403 and you should figure out how to authenticate. You could do this for example from the “network” tab in the f12(inspect element) window of your browser, and analyze the request.

Comment: You may have been blacklisted or rate-limited if you have made too many requests.  I was able to initially download the image successfully via both `wget` and `curl`.  However, after a handful of attempts I am now receiving th 403 Forbidden response.